# get0, set1 functions in openssl

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate

In openssl we have functions with get0 for example X`509_get0_subject_key_id`, `GENERAL_NAME_get0_value`, `SSL_CTX_set1_client_cert_type`, `SSL_CTX_set1_server_cert_type` to name a few. Here we have get0, set1, what these numbers 0 and 1 here stands for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the introduction to the libraries in the OpenSSL guide (new in the 3.2 version but the content is mostly applicable to older versions too):

https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.2/man7/ossl-guide-libraries-introduction.html

In particular see the section "Library Conventions" where this is described.

In summary 0 means ownership of the object is passed to the parent object (for a set0/add0 call) or retained by the parent (for a get0) call.

A 1 means ownership is not passed/retained. Instead a copy (or "up ref") of the object is made.

Comment: In 3.1 down it was in [crypto(7)](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.1/man7/crypto.html#LIBRARY-CONVENTIONS). And many, though not all, of the individual routine pages reiterate "you should/should not free the pointer" or something similar.